# bash source file with some modification

Tags: shell-script

I want to source a file in bash script. I know we can do -

```
. /path/to/file/file.cfg
OR
source /path/to/file/file.cfg
```

But I am writing a single bash script in the world of Python scripts and need to use a config file created for Python scripts -

Python config file -

```
[section 1]
param1=val1
param2=val2

[section 2]
param1=val11
param2=val22
```

bash script -

```
source /path/to/python_config_file

echo $param1
```

Error I get -

> /path/to/python_config_file: line 1: $'[section 1]\r': command not
>   found

I tried to remove the [ ] lines -

```
source `sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' /path/to/python_config_file`
echo $param1
```

It dumps all the variables as output -

> source $'\r' $'param1=val1\r' $'param2=val2\r' $'param1=val11\r' $'param2=val22\r'
>
> : No such file or directory
>   + echo

How do I resolve this? I know I can create a config file for bash but the issue is that the client doesn't want multiple config files as it'll become maintenance nightmare plus python + bash configs have to be synced.

Comment: Your file has CRLF line endings not standard LF endings. Convert it to unix style using `unix2dos  /path/to/python_config_file`

Comment: The bigger problem I see is that bash's value for "param1" (for example) would be overwritten with the last value in the file; you haven't distinguished "section 1" from "section 2" & etc.

Comment: Hi @Jeff, good catch! but this is temp file I had created quickly to demonstrate my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to remove the Windows-style endings from your file. If you don't need to use the file on Windows, you can simply run `dos2unix /path/to/file/file.cfg`. Then, if you're using `bash`, you can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
. <(grep = /path/to/file/file.cfg)
```

This will let you `source` only those lines of `file.cfg` that contain a `=`, which should be exactly what you need.

If you can't/don't want to modify the file to remove the `\r`s, you can do thsi when reading it instead:

```
. <(grep = /path/to/file/file.cfg | tr -d '\r')
```

Comment: Hi @terdon, thanks for the solution. It worked!

Comment: Hi @terdon, I think I'm facing the issue what Jeff has pointed out so is it possible to read only the lines after a particular section - [section 1] or [section 2]. If I supply the section name while executing the bash script?

Comment: @sopana that's a considerably more complicated question. Can't you just change the names of the config variables so they are not repeated? Make it `section1_param1` instead of `param1`? You can't use `source` to get different values into a variable of the same name. So if you can't change the names, then please ask a new question explaining the entire situation.